# Gitlab Users and Groups Management

Tags: gitlab

How to restrict the GitLab project to one group, so that any new user or user from another group cannot be added?

For example, two groups are created in GitLab `groupA`, `groupB`.

When I am the owner of `groupA` for a project.

I should not able to add user of `groupB` and the individual user should also be restricted.

Comment: I your are not an owner/maintainer for groupB, you cannot add user to groupB. Just don't add owner/maintainer permissions to people who should not have them. Same thing for individual user: train your owners/maintainers so they only add relevant people to groups/projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is cannot valid. One user belong to 0, 1 or many group(s).

See document: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/